# Animate changing iCarouselOptionSpacing with iCarousel

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoapods, icarousel

I was trying to use iCarousel for one my app, I need to achieve something like the image below [image]

How to animate sliding Item 2 to Item 1? How to animate the change of distance between the elements?
Animation show only first time when open, then iCarouselOptionSpacing will be always the same.

Comment: Which carousel type you are using ? A linear type can be useful for you. also with some customisation will required.

Comment: @anshul-systematix i use "iCarouselTypeLinear", what type of customisation do you mean?